# I'm sending a command to a serial COM port in C# and not getting data back, but when I use Putty I get data - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#-3.0, serial-port

I have a C# application, which I'm writing to try automate data extraction from a serial device. As the title of my question says, I have tried the exact same commands in Putty and I get data back. Could somebody please tell me what I have missed out, so that I can get the same data out with my C# application please?

Basically, I need to COM6, a speed/baud of 57600, and send the command without quotes "UH". I should be presented with a few lines of text data, which appears to only work on Putty.

As a quick test, I threw this together:

```
private void SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort();

private void getHistory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort_DataReceived);
  serialPort.PortName = "COM6";
  serialPort.BaudRate = 57600;

  serialPort.Open();
  if (serialPort.IsOpen())
  {
    serialPort.Write("UH");
  }
}

private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  string result = serialPort.ReadExisting();
  Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate{ textbox1.AppendText(result); }));
}
```

The DataReceived event does get fired, but it only returns back the "UH" I sent up, no further data. Any help with this problem would be highly appreciated!

- Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, without further detail of the device in question, it is hard to say for sure, but two things spring to mind:

Firstly, what comms protocol does the device require? You have set up the baud rate, but have no mention of data bits, parity, or stop bits. I *think* the .NET serial port class defaults to 8,N,1. If your device is the same then you should be fine. If it is not, then it won't work.

Secondly, does the device require any kind of termination to the data to define a complete packet? Commonly this can be the data sent is appended with a carriage return and a line feed (0x0D and 0x0A), or perhaps is has a prefix of STX (0x02) and a suffix of ETX (0x03).

Any message that the device responds with is likely to be in the same format too.

I don't know how Putty works, but check the setup and see if it is appending anything to the message you type, and the protocol. Hyperterminal does this too, so you could test it with this also.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me, I'm struggling a bit with this one. The device in question is a Oregon RFID Datalogger, and the other settings you mentioned are:

Data bits: 8
Parity: None
Stop bits: 1
Flow control: Hardware

I will try added on a carriage return to the end of my command strings and see if that helps.

Comment: @JustinN : No problem. Presumably there must be some sort of spec or manual for the RFID device? The CRLF suggestion is just a guess on my part. It may be more complicated than that of course!

Comment: they provided a printed copy of the manual which basically lists all the terminal commands, along with basic instructions to connect via Hyperterminal for Windows, Putty for Vista/Windows 7, OSX/Linux/Unix terminal emulator. I could not find any settings for what is tagged on the end of Putty within itself, but I will try looking it up on Google in a moment. I just wanted to say that I just tried "UH\r\n" and I got back extra data - scrambled, but still more than what I had before!

Comment: what was needed was "UH\n\r", and for some reason all data on the DataReceived event was garbage, so instead I had running constantly in a separate thread a method checking the serial port for data. On top of which, ReadLine() gave back garbage, whilst Read() gave back everything. All in all, thanks to your clever suggestion, I've got my data! Thank you!

Comment: @JustinN: Sounds like your are on the right track now. Good luck  :)